# Looping PHP PDO query result through a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know similar questions have been asked before, but i am not completely satisfied with the answers. Alternatively, I am looking for a better/simpler way to do this.

Basically there is a table like this:

```
id  object     Desc
1   Apple      Fruit
2   Orange     Fruit
3   cabbage    Vegetable
```

A function like this:

```
function description($object)
{
if ($object == apple)
return "Red like an apple";

if($object == orange)
return "Orange like an orange";

if($object == cabbage)
return "green like a cabbage";
}
```

I want to execute some kind of a select all in PHP PDO that returns

```
id  object                  Desc
1   red like an apple       Fruit
2   orange like an orange   Fruit
3   green like a cabbage    Vegetable
```

Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please do not ask for ready made answers here.

Comment: And by the way `if ($object == apple)` is wrong `if ($object == 'apple')` is proper as its String.

Comment: It was just an illustration. I am obviously not writing this exact same function in my code

Comment: Ram, what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best method that i could find.

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $result){
$result['object'] = description($result['object']);
$myresult[] = $result; }

echo json_encode($myresult);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have 2 follow up questions: 1. Is there a way to limit the callback to specific indexes in an associate array? (to just index "object" in  my case)  2. Wouldn't performance suffer if you call back for every index, rather than just one?